# Angular circular dependency - Components call each other

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

In my Angular App, I have 2 Components that can open each other as modals.
From component A you can open component B, and from component B you can open component A.
How can I achieve this without having a circular dependency?
I tried moving the modal calls to a service, but both components need this service injected and I have the circular dependency again.

I also read something about injecting with forwardRef, but I could not get it to work.
I tried to inject the service like this in the constructor of the components:

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => CircularService)) private circularService: CircularService
```

Comment: If you create a modalsService, with an open method, which creates modals dynamically, then A and B can inject the service and open any modal without a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have a solution for your problem, we can use InjectionTokens and provide them in a shared Module.
First component  token: component-a-token.ts

```
export const COMPONENT_A_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('ComponentAToken');
```

Second component token: component-b-token.ts

```
export const COMPONENT_B_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('ComponentBToken');
```

Then provide components in module:

```
 providers: [
        RenderService,
        { provide: COMPONENT_A_TOKEN, useValue: ComponentA },
        { provide: COMPONENT_B_TOKEN, useValue: ComponentB}
    ]
```

this allows us to inject components class:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-a',
    templateUrl: './a.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(@Inject(COMPONENT_B_TOKEN) private componentB) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! I actually only needed one Token to break the cycle